# How to find JCL MSGCLASS=?

Tags: mainframe, zos, jcl

I am working on a basic JCL script from the IBM publib.boulder site.  Below is the JCL that simply sorts a list of characters in ascending order.  The job executes just fine, but the contents of SYSIN are not printed to the job status, as is shown in the [publib demonstration](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/basics/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.zos.zjcl/zjclt_codingyourownjcl.htm)

Here is my code:

```
//SORT JOB OTIMPF01,CLASS=A,MSGCLASS=H 
/*                                     
//STEP1 EXEC PGM=SORT                  
//SYSIN DD *  SORT   FIELDS=(1,75,CH,A)
/*                                     
//SYSOUT  DD   SYSOUT=*                
//SYSIN   DD   *                       
NEPTUNE                                
PLUTO                                  
EARTH                                  
VENUS                                  
MERCURY                                
MARS                                   
URANUS                                 
SATURN                                 
JUPITER                                
/*                                     
//SORTOUT  DD SYSOUT=*                 
/*
```

I know that it has something to do with the MSGCLASS= statement.  The sample code from publib uses MSGCLASS=H, and I was told that that is different depending on who set the option on the mainframe.  My question is, how can I figure out what my mainframe's MSGCLASS is set to without having to ask anyone?  Again, I just want the result of the characters sorted in ascending order to be displayed in the job status.

It should look like this...

```
ICE134I 0 NUMBER OF BYTES SORTED: 720 
 ICE180I 0 HIPERSPACE STORAGE USED = 0K BYTES 
 ICE188I 0 DATA SPACE STORAGE USED = 0K BYTES 
 ICE052I 0 END OF DFSORT   
 EARTH 
 JUPITER    
 MARS 
 MERCURY 
NEPTUNE                                                                                    
 PLUTO 
 SATURN  
 URANUS 
 VENUS
```

...Only my job status read-out does not display the characters Earth through Venus in the output of the job status.

My job status looks like this...

```
IEF373I STEP/STEP1   /START 2014002.1033                                                                                           
IEF374I STEP/STEP1   /STOP  2014002.1033 CPU    0MIN 00.00SEC SRB    0MIN 00.00SEC VIRT   212K SYS   248K EXT       8K SYS   11592K
IEF375I  JOB/SORT    /START 2014002.1033                                                                                           
IEF376I  JOB/SORT    /STOP  2014002.1033 CPU    0MIN 00.00SEC SRB    0MIN 00.00SEC                                                 
ICE000I 1 - CONTROL STATEMENTS FOR 5694-A01, Z/OS DFSORT V1R5 - 10:33 ON THU JAN 02, 2014 -                                        
ICE010A 0 NO SORT OR MERGE CONTROL STATEMENT                                                                                       
ICE751I 0 C5-K05352 C6-Q95214 E7-K90000                                                                                            
ICE052I 3 END OF DFSORT
```

I imagine it has to do with properly setting the MSGCLASS.  I have tried Googling z/OS MSGCLASS and to no surprise, it comes up with very little.

Comment: ALSO! I am getting a COND CODE 0016.

Comment: Yeah, CC16 is because of the `ICE010A` also.

Comment: Why don't you want to ask someone what MSGCLASS to use?

Comment: Our mainframe acts as a testing environment.  We are not hosting a data center.  The engineer who set it up is currently out of town.  Obviously I could have called him but I figured there would be an easy way to find the MSGCLASS.  To make this short, we don't really have a dedicated systems programmer or admin or anything like that.  While there are very intelligent people here, they are often busy with other things so I usually have my head in IBM documentation, which is (no offense) not always the best :)

Comment: No offense taken at all. IBM has been known for its obtuse and not-always-accurate documentation for decades. ;)

Comment: Also, you might be interested in the IBM-MAIN LISTSERV. Go to https://listserv.ua.edu/cgi-bin/wa?A0=IBM-MAIN to sign up. You can also browse the mirror bit.listserv.ibm-main on Google Groups or other news reader.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key problem is `ICE010A 0 NO SORT OR MERGE CONTROL STATEMENT`.  Assuming you transcribed your JCL correctly here, you typed:

```
//SYSIN DD *  SORT   FIELDS=(1,75,CH,A)
/*
```

In which case, you presented an empty input stream to `SORT`, because the `SORT   FIELDS=(1,75,CH,A)` was treated as a comment on the `DD` statement.

You should have typed:

```
//SYSIN DD *
  SORT   FIELDS=(1,75,CH,A)
/*
```

Comment: Thank you!  I was just coding what the IBM documentation had written.  I guess they made a mistake.  One question though... How come your line with SORT does not have to begin with '//' marks?

Comment: You've got a lot more reading to do :-)  Short story, `//SYSIN DD *` means "_everything starting from the next card/line until a card/line with `/*` in columns 1-2 is the SYSIN input stream_". `SYSIN` is the mainframe equivalent of a standard-input stream.

Comment: Great, this has been very informative.  You are right, I have a lot more reading to do.  I'm sure you can imagine what it took for me to get this dataset on a tape in the first place ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try **ST jobname** in SDSF and it will show you all the output. ST is the status of jobs and shows all the output for all jobs on the system submitted or finished.

Also if you are looking on the held queue **H jobname** then see what output classes for you job it shows and try changing the msgclass to one of the classes shown on the held queue. For example on my system I can see class X and H on the held queue but only see class A when I use the **ST** command

Comment: Thank you, I was able to find the CLASS= parm with ST.  I now know that I am CLASS=A, which I already had in the JCL.  I cannot see what you are talking about with H <jobname>.  It shows that the class is still A.  So I am assuming the CLASS=A, and MSGCLASS=A.  I set those parms in my JCL and I still cannot see the character output that I was hoping to see.  There must be something else wrong with my code.  Thank you, the H <jobname> was a helpful resource which rules out any possible MSGCLASS or CLASS parm errors.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, you have uncovered a documentation error in the manual page you link to. However, you have also introduced an error of your own.

For your Mainframe installed SORT package (likely to be IBM's DFSORT or the competing SyncSort, but also possible the further rival CA-SORT):

```
//SYSIN DD whatever
```

Is where you put the control cards.

In the above, whatever can be *, DATA or parameters for an actual dataset.

The DDNAME for *input* to the SORT program you use is SORTIN:

```
//SORTIN DD whatever (same as above)
```

You accidentally made that SYSIN as well. It should be:

```
//SYSIN   DD   *                       
NEPTUNE                                
PLUTO                                  
EARTH                                  
VENUS                                  
MERCURY                                
MARS                                   
URANUS                                 
SATURN                                 
JUPITER
```

You should then see the output from the example in your SORTOUT spool file.

There are other DDs for when you do other things with SORT (like MERGE, JOINKEYS, OUTFIL) which can or do use differently-named DDs. It is also possible to override the standard names, but you would not be able to override them to SYSIN.

//SYSIN DD * is a bit like STDIN, but don't get carried away with the comparison. By convention, many Mainframe utilities use SYSIN for input. If a JCL-stream contains "cards" not preceded by a DDName, then a DDName of SYSIN will be automatically generated. COBOL has an ACCEPT verb for a type of input, and the default DD for this is SYSIN. However, simply including a SYSIN in the JCL for a step is no guarantee that it will be used. If the program on the EXEC does not use SYSIN, then simply including SYSIN is not going to cause data to be read from there.

Comment: Aye, the mainframe used DFSORT.  I will have to study more of what you are saying here.  I'll change my //SORTIN to //SYSIN and see the difference.  The script actually works as is so I will have a look at the differences in output.

Comment: @Mac It may have been a pasto then. In your question you have no SORTIN, but two SYSINs.